# QuickBlox updateGroupChatDialog for Android is not updating dialog's custom data

Tags: android, quickblox

I have a QBChatDialog that has a custom data, I am trying to save user's Id when they accept my invitation to the "accepted" arraylist of my dialog's custom Data , but when I update the dialog the custom data has not been Updated in the retu . could you please help me with that.

```
QBDialogCustomData customData = firstDialog.getCustomData(); 
ArrayList<Integer>goingArray= (ArrayList<Integer>)customData.get("accepted"); 
goingArray.add(17429329); 
customData.put("accepted", goingArray); firstDialog.setCustomData(customData); 
QBDialogRequestBuilder requestBuilder = new QBDialogRequestBuilder(); 
Performer performer = QBRestChatService.updateGroupChatDialog(firstDialog,requestBuilder); 
performer.performAsync( new QBEntityCallback<QBChatDialog>() {
  @Override 
  public void onSuccess(QBChatDialog qbDialog, Bundle bundle) { 
     refresh(qbDialog); 
    } 
   @Override 
   public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
     Log.d(TAG, "e"+e); }
     });
```